# distributing n people with k fields and l possible values for each field to buckets of common fields

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have n people, each person have k properites and each property have l possible values. for example, a property can be 'car color' and the values ['red','green','blue',...].
I want to distribute the people to groups where each group is a subset of the possible combination of properties.
For example, lets say I have 4 persons alice, bob, eve, rod. 3 properties a,b,c and 3 values for each prperty, a:[1,2,3], b:[4,5,6], c:[7,8,9].
then in this scanario:

```
alice = [2,4,7]
bob = [1,4,7]
eve = [2,6,8]
rod = [2,4,9]
the groups will be: 
[alice, eve]
[alice, bob]
[alice, rod]
[eve,rod]
[bob,rod]
[alice, bob, rod]
```

where 0 is a trivial value that each property can have.

I thought on an approach that each person will be assigned an array of numbers of a certain basis.
(Like in the example)
And then, iterating over all the people combinations: for each couple I will get the "bitwise AND" and then find the subsets of the result. for example, lets take alice and bob:
the 'bitwise AND' will result in [0,4,7] and then the subsets will be [4],[7],[4,7].
I will have a hash table where the key is the possible subset and the value will be a list containing all belonging persons.

Comment: Hello. Why not `[Alice, Bob, Rod]`?

Comment: Alice, Eve, and Rod all have a 2; should they be in a group?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particularly clever way to do this. You need to iterate on all the properties and all the people, so the algorithm has to be Ω(n k).

Here in python, using a python dict which is really a hashmap, to group people by property value:

```py
n_properties = 3
data = {
    'alice': [2,4,7],
    'bob': [1,4,7],
    'eve': [2,6,8],
    'rod': [2,4,9],
}

def subgroups(data, n_properties):
    for i in range(n_properties):
        d = {}
        for name,props in data.items():
            d.setdefault(props[i], []).append(name)
        yield from d.values()

# using set to remove duplicates, but messing the order:
print(set(map(tuple, subgroups(data, n_properties))))
# {('alice', 'bob'), ('rod',), ('alice', 'eve', 'rod'), ('alice', 'bob', 'rod'), ('bob',), ('eve',)}

# without removing duplicates, and keeping order:
print(list(subgroups(data, n_properties)))
# [['alice', 'eve', 'rod'], ['bob'],
#  ['alice', 'bob', 'rod'], ['eve'],
#  ['alice', 'bob'], ['eve'], ['rod']]
```